# PostgreSQL group by column with aggregate

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to `group by` id and select the `task` with min/max `seq` as `start` and `end`

```
 id | task | seq    
----+------+-----
  1 | aaa  |   1 
  1 | bbb  |   2
  1 | ccc  |   3
```

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  CASE WHEN seq = MIN(seq) THEN task AS start,
  CASE WHEN seq = MAX(seq) THEN task AS end
FROM table
GROUP BY id;
```

But this results in

```
ERROR:  column "seq" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

But I do not want group by `seq`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses arrays:

```
SELECT id, 
       (ARRAY_AGG(task ORDER BY seq ASC))[1] as start_task,
       (ARRAY_AGG(task ORDER BY seq DESC))[1] as end_task
FROM table
GROUP BY id;
```

Another method uses window functions with `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
select distinct id,
       first_value(task) over (partition by id order by seq) as start_task,
       first_value(task) over (partition by id order by seq desc) as end_task
from t;
```

Comment: The window example does exactly what i need. Can I use `last_value` for the end select as well? I tried that and it results in a different output.

Comment: @Pascal . . . I generally recommend using `first_value()` with a descending sort.  The two functions have some differences because the default window frame affects `last_value()` differently from `first_value()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions with a derived table:

```
select id, task, min_seq as start, max_seq as "end"
from (
  select id, task, seq, 
         max(seq) over (partition by id) as max_seq,
         min(seq) over (partition by id) as min_seq
  from the_table
) t
where seq in (max_seq, min_seq)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option here would be to use `ROW_NUMBER` along with aggregation and pivoting logic:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY seq) rn_min,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY seq DESC) rn_max
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_min = 1 THEN task END) AS start,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_max = 1 THEN task END) AS end
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo